# get value only works using .first, but if i try to loop for each item with .each it does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to select multiples images when pressing the upload button and be able to see all of them. At the moment I made a simplify version where I want to see the url of the images in a label. At the moment I only can accomplish it by getting the first or last element:

```
var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON()
meta_label.text(media_attachment.url)
```

But i really want to see all the url, so keeping that code in mind i tried to made a modified version using .each like this:

```
var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').each(function(){
  var media_attachment_tr = $(this).first().toJSON();
  meta_label.append(media_attachment_tr.url);
});
    meta_label.append(" isdone");
```

But this does nothing, even the "isdone" part is not appending to the code and i have no idea of why this is happening. There is a way to make this itereable?

Comment: Did you already check the console for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `.each` wrong. [jQuery's `.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) takes 2 arguments. The first being the object that you want to iterate over and the second one is the callback, see this example from the documentation:

```js
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

Additionally, the callback function takes also 2 arguments that you can use in the body of the function: the index and the value of the item from the object that it iterates over.

If you want to use jQuery's `.each`, you'll need to restructure the code, but I'd suggest using [JavaScript's `.forEach`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp) instead, which does sort of what you have in your code. You just need to add one or two argument in the callback function - the first being the current item from the list and the second, optional, is the index.

Your code (without insuring functionality) could look like this:

```
var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').forEach(function(media){
  var media_attachment_tr = media.toJSON();
  meta_label.append(media_attachment_tr.url);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanaition, foreach worked fine modified a bit. I still need practice with javascript